# Does calling the get method of created document reference count as a read?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

In the Python Firestore API, after a document is added to a firestore collection a timestamp and a document reference of the created document are returned. Would it count as a read in the database if the `get` method on the returned document reference is called?

Comment: Short answer: YES

Answer (score 1):

Any time you invoke `get()` on a document reference, you will be billed 1 read if the program was able to reach the Firestore backend.  The document data behind a reference is not cached after a write: it will be read again for each call to `get()`.